# How can I gitignore everything except *.txt?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

For example. I have a directory containing a mix of txt files and binaries of various extensions, and I only want to version-control the *.txt files

Answer (score 5):

.gitignore:

```
# ignore everything
*
# but not subdirectories
!*/
# and not .txt files
!*.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `!` to negate a pattern.

```
*
!*.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

for including txt only in directory structure you have to ignore all except (negate) txt, and sub-directory. So make some change on .gitignore.

```
*
!.gitattributes
!.gitignore
!readme.md
!.gitkeep
!*.txt
!*/
```

Answer (score 0):

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file
>   excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. If a
>   negated pattern matches, this will override lower precedence patterns
>   sources. Put a backslash ("\") in front of the first "!" for patterns
>   that begin with a literal "!", for example, "\!important!.txt".
>   [source](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)